# How to parse the field of a binded object to int in the HTML using ThymeLeaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

```
<form th:action="@{/gustos}" method="post" th:object="${gusto}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <h2> Borrar Gusto</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm using the binded object **th:object="${gusto}"** to access each of the object attributes in the HTML.

The hidden input that's capturing the id is parsing it to a String ... I need to parse it again so I can access the variable from my controller or to do the following:

```
<div class="row delete" th:id="*{gusto.id != null}">
        <div class="col s12 l8">
            <form th:action="@{|/gustos/${gusto.id}/delete|}" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="button">Borrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But it's not letting me sience the field is a String and it's expecting an int.

Is there any way to parse that field (the 'id') in the HTML using ThymeLeaf ?

This is my controller's method that handles the view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gustos/{id}/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteGustoId(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
    Gusto gusto = gustoService.findGustoById(id);
    model.addAttribute("gusto", gusto);
    gustoService.delete(gusto);
    return "deleteGusto";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is on your `th:action`. You are using a syntax that I haven't seen or used, so I am not sure if it should work. I haven being using this other syntax way, that has always work. Try changing your code with the following one.

```
<form th:action="@{'/gustos/'+ ${gusto.id} +'/delete'}" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="button">Borrar</button>
</form>
```

**Update**

Since, what we are getting is a `String`, we could do a simple cast, in our Controller. This if we are sure the parameter we are receiving is an int.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gustos/{id}/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteGustoId(@PathVariable String id, Model model){
    int numId = Integer.parseInt(id);
    Gusto gusto = gustoService.findGustoById(numId);
    model.addAttribute("gusto", gusto);
    gustoService.delete(gusto);
    return "deleteGusto";
}
```

The odd thing, is that Spring should do the casting automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks Alan !! Same problem thought ... Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "deleteGusto"

Comment: I believe the sintax was alright .... it's just different, but valid for concatenation

Comment: Yeah, I imagined, is just that I haven't seen it before so I was wondering. Odd that it is not working.

Comment: You are sure ${gusto.id} is an int? Also, it is normally better to use Integer, in case it comes null. Sometimes it can avoid some issues.

Comment: It's not working cause the hidden input that's storing the objects id it casting the id to a String (sience it's being stored in an input) ... I need to re-cast that value from String to int once again but I don't know how to do it in the ThymeLeaf template, maybe you know how to ?

Comment: Well if it is a String, then I wouldn't do the casting using Thymeleaf, but Java. So, I would instead use the code I just edited. Still, I find odd that your `@PathVariable` is not being casted automatically to int, since it is an int.

Comment: I never asked, what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: It is indeed very odd ... I've tried casting it in the controller before, but still the same error :(
This is the error message: Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "deleteGusto"

Comment: Well, somehow, your input's value is "deleteGusto", and that's what's causing the issue. So your problem comes from the model itself, which have `${gusto.id}` with a value of "deleteGusto".

Comment: "deleteGusto" is the name of the view I'm trying to render !!! The model is Ok sience it's working with another view as expected

Comment: The problem isn't that java can't convert Strings to integers -- that is automatic. 
 The error message specifically says: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "deleteGusto"` -- java is trying to convert the string "deleteGusto" to an integer (which can't be done).  You have to examine your code, and find why the string is "deleteGusto" is in your url instead of the real id of the Gusto.